# How can I place multiple things in an ag-grid cell?

Tags: ag-grid

ag-grid has some nice feature for my application needs and I plan to use it. However, I want to know whether it's possible to place multiple things in a single cell. Specifically, I want to place a multi-line code snippet, a "copy me" button and some link. Is this possible?

Comment: pls provide the link for each feature to ag-doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-line content with **AutoRowHeight** - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/#auto-row-height

Buttons and Links with Custom **CellRenderer** Components - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#angular-cell-render-components

Links can also be done with **cellClicked** event - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#selection